# REGEXMATCH Count Zero If None (Google Sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to count all cells that contain this exact string somewhere in the cell "(w)"
The formula below shows 1 when there are none found
How can I make it show 0 if none are found?

```
COUNTA(FILTER(D2:D55, REGEXMATCH(D2:D55, "(w)")))
```

(This works correctly if there are one or more)

This also still counts 1 if there are none

```
COUNTA(FILTER(D2:D55, REGEXMATCH(D2:D55, "\(w\)")))
```

Comment: Why regex? Use `=COUNTIF(D2:D55, "(w)")`

Comment: I guess you meant to add wildcards? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: To tell the truth, I read the question like if there exact cell value is `(w)`. If a cell can contain the value, then yes, `"*(w)*"` is required

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D2:D55, "*(w)*")`, you mean, because the `(w)` only needs to be "somewhere in the cell". But it would be best if the answer included a solution that accepts a regex pattern (for the situations where that is needed)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this should have been closed - the count of 1 is due to the filter returning #N/A (no matches found in filter evaluation) and not really anything to do with whether or not you use regex.